# Center Horizontally div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I want to center horizontally a div but it works in Google Chrome but in IE not work.

This is my code:

```css
.app-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100%);
  position: relative;
}
.pagination--custom {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.pagination {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-content">
  <div class="pagination--custom">
    <div class="pagination">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support `width: fit-content;`

Answer (score 1):

`fit-content` is experimental and won't work in ie or edge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width.

Make it `display: inline-block` instead and put `text-align: center` on the parent

```css
.app-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100%);
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
.pagination--custom {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.pagination {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-content">
  <div class="pagination--custom">
    <div class="pagination">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This: Tested its working!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      .pagination--custom {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          border: 1px solid #000;
          margin: 0 auto;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="app-content">
  <div class="pagination--custom">
    <div class="pagination">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

JUST SET `margin: 0 auto;` for pagination

Comment: then define width in pagination--custom to make it center. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `margin: 0 auto;` has to be on `.pagination` and remove `width: fit-content;`.

```css
.app-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100%);
  position: relative;
}
.pagination--custom {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.pagination {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-content">
  <div class="pagination--custom">
    <div class="pagination">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my real code, .pagination don't have a width predefined